# Sklearn performance issue with Dask

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask

I am trying to speedup a piece of Sklearn code using Dask, without success.
Sklearn (without Dask) is always faster.

Below is my code, where I am comparing **dask-ml**, **dask + joblib + sklearn** and **sklearn**. I suspect I am doing something obviously wrong.
Do you have any suggestions on how to modify the code below in order to get a practical performance gain?

```py
import time
import dask
import joblib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.array as da
import dask.distributed
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask_ml.linear_model as dlinear_model
from sklearn import linear_model


data = np.random.rand(100000000, 2)
nbytes = data.nbytes
print('SIZE [BYTES] = ', nbytes)
print('SIZE [MB] = ', nbytes * 1e-6)
print('SIZE [GB] = ', nbytes * 1e-9)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y'])




def main_dask_native():
    print('DASK NATIVE ---')

    s = time.time()
    npartitions = nbytes / (100 * 1e6)
    print('npartitions = ', npartitions)
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=npartitions)
    X = ddf.to_dask_array()
    x = X[:,0]
    y = X[:,1]
    x = da.atleast_2d(x).T
    y = da.atleast_2d(y).T
    print(type(x))
    print(type(y))
    x.compute_chunk_sizes()
    y.compute_chunk_sizes()
    print('elapsed [operations]: ', time.time() - s, 's.')

    s = time.time()
    regressor = dlinear_model.LinearRegression()
    model = regressor.fit(x, y)
    y_pred = model.predict(x)
    print('elapsed [learning]: ', time.time() - s, 's.')



def main_dask():
    print('DASK ---')
    c = dask.distributed.Client()

    s = time.time()
    npartitions = nbytes / (100 * 1e6)
    print('npartitions = ', npartitions)
    ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=npartitions)
    X = ddf.to_dask_array()
    x = X[:,0]
    y = X[:,1]
    x = da.atleast_2d(x).T
    y = da.atleast_2d(y).T
    print('elapsed [operations]: ', time.time() - s, 's.')

    s = time.time()
    with joblib.parallel_backend('dask', scheduler='threads', n_jobs=16):
        regressor = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        model = regressor.fit(x, y)
        y_pred = model.predict(x)
    print('elapsed [learning]: ', time.time() - s, 's.')



def main_sklearn():
    print('SKLEARN ---')
    # c = dask.distributed.Client()

    s = time.time()
    x = df.loc[:,'x']
    y = df.loc[:,'y']
    x = np.atleast_2d(x).T
    y = np.atleast_2d(y).T
    print('elapsed [operations]: ', time.time() - s, 's.')

    s = time.time()
    regressor = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    model = regressor.fit(x, y)
    y_pred = model.predict(x)
    print('elapsed [learning]: ', time.time() - s, 's.')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = time.time()
    main_dask_native()
    print('Elapsed time = ', time.time() - s, 's')

    s = time.time()
    main_dask()
    print('Elapsed time = ', time.time() - s, 's')
    
    s = time.time()
    main_sklearn()
    print('Elapsed time = ', time.time() - s, 's')
```